# Branch.io custom url shortener & universal links

Tags: ios, branch.io

Hypothesis:
I have a custom URL shortener that redirects to a branch.io long URL.
That custom URL domain is registered in my app's entitlements file for Universal Links.
When a user taps a short link, the app opens and calls application:continueUserActivity:restorationHandler:...
In that method I get the redirect URL (branch) that stands behind the short link, create a new NSUserActivity based on the new link and call "continueUserActivity" method (with the new activity as a parameter) from Branch SDK.

The problem is that the callback from Branch SDK doesn't return anything connected to that link. It returns as if no URL was passed.

If I hardcode the link that comes from redirect and call Branch SDK immediately, without waiting for the redirect response, then everything works fine. I suppose it's something time related in Branch SDK.

The question is: how can I make Branch recognize the link and give me back the params I need when using the redirect scheme described above? (I want to use my own URL shortener, not the one from Branch)

Comment: Alex with Branch here: this is definitely a somewhat unusual application of our linking system! We provide the built-in URL shortener to help avoid the pitfalls inherent in a more complicated process like the one you described, so it's hard to be certain exactly where things might be breaking. Could you help me understand the rationale behind using custom shortener?

Comment: how did u get the link behind the shorten url? In my case i want the url behind shorten url. @stonycis

Comment: @Sumeet.Jain I use "setTaskWillPerformHTTPRedirectionBlock" method from AFHTTPSessionManager (AFNetworking) to get the redirect behind the short URL.

Answer (score 0):

In determining whether a Branch link needs to be handled or not, Branch checks to verify that the NSUserActivity is of type NSUserActivityTypeBrowsingWeb. If it is, Branch checks the .webpageURL to determine if it is a Branch link. If it is not, Branch understands that no Branch link has been clicked.

To manually pass a Branch link into the SDK after the app has been opened some other way there are two functions available: .continue and .handleDeepLink.

**.continue**

```
    let activity = NSUserActivity(activityType: "NSUserActivityTypeBrowsingWeb")
    activity.webpageURL = URL(string: "https://testbed-swift.app.link/77Q527xswy")
    Branch.getInstance().continue(activity);
```

**.handleDeepLink**

```
    Branch.getInstance().handleDeepLink(URL(string: "https://testbed-swift.app.link/77Q527xswy"))
```

If you call one of these methods, the Branch SDK will handle the Branch link passed in. If these methods are not working for you, I would check to verify that you are actually passing in a working Branch link in the code and not the shortlink that you are using to open the app.